# Measuring siginificant difference between Likert-scale value?

Tags: statistical-significance, likert

I have two tables, each containing 64 5-point Likert-scale scores. I would like to investigate if there is a significant difference between the two tables.

Which test would be best to use in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by 'different'.

- Likert scores are ordinal.
  Do you want to know whether one set of scores is generally higher?
- Likert scores are categorical. Do you want to know whether the sample distributions into the five categories differ significantly?

**Higher or Lower?** Suppose scores are integers 1 through 5, with 5 indicating the
most favorable view on a topic. Sample `a` tends to have higher (more favorable) scores than sample `b`. [Sampling and computation in R.]

```
set.seed(719)
a = sample(1:5, 64, rep=T, pr=c(1,1,1,6,6)/15)
b = sample(1:5, 64, rep=T, pr=c(3,3,3,3,3)/15)
table(a)
a
 1  2  3  4  5 
 7  4  9 21 23 
table(b)
b
 1  2  3  4  5 
13 13 13 12 13
```

We do a two-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) test on vectors `a` and `b`.

```
wilcox.test(a,b)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  a and b
W = 2683.5, p-value = 0.001898
alternative hypothesis: 
   true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Looking at empirical CDF (ECDF) plots of the two groups of Likert scores, we see that
scores `a` *dominate* (are generally higher than) scores `b`. That is the ECDF
for `a` (blue) lies to the right of the ECDF for `b` (orange). [To make an ECDF plot, sort $n=64$ scores from smallest to largest, starting at $0$ at the left, jump up at each score by $k/n$ if there are $k$ observations tied at a value, ending at $1$ at the right.]

```
plot(ecdf(a), col="blue", lwd=3)
 lines(ecdf(b), col="orange", lwd=2, lty="dotted", pch="o")
```

[image]

**More or Less Controversial?** Sample `a` has more extreme scores (strongly opposed or in favor) then does sample `b`.

```
set.seed(2020)
a = sample(1:5, 64, rep=T, pr=c(5,2,1,2,5)/15)
b = sample(1:5, 64, rep=T, pr=c(2,3,5,3,2)/15)
A = tabulate(a);  B = tabulate(b)

TBL = rbind(A,B);  TBL
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
A   26    7    7    5   19
B    7   14   20   15    8
```

We do a chi-squared test of homogeneity, using a table `TBL` of scores `a` and `b`.

```
chisq.test(TBL)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 29.013, df = 4, p-value = 7.768e-06
```

We strongly reject the null hypothesis (P-value near $0)$ that the profiles of favor and disfavor
are the same for groups with scores `a` and `b`.

Because scores are not generally higher for one group than for the other, a Wilcoxon signed rank test would have found no significant difference between the groups.

```
wilcox.test(a,b)$p.val
[1] 0.2067968
```

*Notes:* (1) We could have done a chi-squared test of homogeneity in the first part and it might have rejected the null hypothesis, but that would not have
answered the question whether one group tends to have higher scores than the other.
(2) It is not necessary for the vector `pr` of relative frequencies
used in the `sample` procedure to sum to unity. R automatically adjusts
the vector to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Bruce. To clarify a bit more: participants were asked about their feeling to a situation "A", and to their feeling to situation "B". This was done through a 5-point Likert score (1=Strongly Agree, 2=Strongly Disagree). I would like to investigate whether situation A reported significantly different results, when compared to situation B.

Comment: Once again: What do you mean by 'different'? One group generally more favorable? or just some different pattern of responses?

Comment: Then I'd say Wilcoxon. // If this is for a course, you might be expected to do a chi-squared test of homogeneity (or independence) -- particularly if that's the topic being studied at the moment.

Comment: I apologise for not explaining it properly. What I'm trying to measure is; lets say situation A has an "average" of 3.75, and situation B has an "average" of 3.93. I'd like to know if the responses to B are different enough, compared to A, to conclude that the responses are significantly different from each other.

Comment: Yes, then Wilcoxon. // Because you use the word 'average', I'm wondering if that is the 'mean'. If so you're treating Likert data as numerical rather than just ordinal categorical. Controversial step: Do you really intend to do _arithmetic_ with category labels? Do two 'favor's cancel out one 'strongly opposed'. People who feel that's OK might even feel comfortable using a t test to see if one group has a higher 'mean' score. (I'm _not_ one of those people. I think interpreting Likert scores as numerical is almost always an exercise in self-delusion.)

Comment: I only used it as numerical data to explain my example, but since it's a Likert scale I definitely won't be treating it as one in my research. Thank you very much for your time in explaining it.

Comment: It is a gross overstatement, and an example of "knee-jerk statistics," to say that you can't treat ordinal data as numeric. It is done all the time. The suggested remedy of using the Wilcoxon test does not help. After all, the Wilcoxon test is just that - a test. The t test based on averages is likely to be more powerful, given the boundedness of the response. In addition, the regular averages are more easily interpreted, despite problems in some cases, than the average ranks, which the Wilcoxon test uses, for estimation purposes.

Comment: I see. What kind of t-test would you propose?

Comment: I thought I made it clear that I would not recommend a t-test. If you insist that Likert scores are numerical, then you might do a two-sample t-test in place of what probably should have been a two-sample Wilcoxon test? // If the t-test. But what if the t test rejects the null hypothesis and the Wilcoxon test does not? Does your field really need one more 'false discovery'? And do you really need to be responsible for it.